Compensating acceleration vectors from IMU orientation
I have an IMU sensor giving me a quaternion of its orientation. I want to be able to mount the IMU as I want on the airplane frame, and still be able to get a quaternion that would be the same as if the board was aligned with the body coordinates.
I know, it's something largely covered on the internet : but I tried eveything and I had to tweak formulas to make this work, which is kinda strange. To be sure it's not a problem with something like swapped axis on my sensor, I want to be sure I'm not making a maths mistake. Here is my operations :
1. Computing the quaternion that describes the rotation to go back to the body frame reference
I have a quaternion $Q_{\text{compensation}}$ that describes the rotation to go from the IMU frame to the body frame coordinate system. Yaw is the Z axis, X is the Roll axis, and Pitch is the Y axis.
To make it "user understable", I'm using a succession of YAW-PITCH-ROLL rotations. For example, starting with the IMU aligned with the body frame, I want to mount it using first a 90° yaw rotation, then a 90° roll rotation, each time around the local axis of my IMU.
Here is how I compute my compensation quaternion :
\begin{align*}
q_{\text{yaw}} &= \text{getQuaternionFromEulers}(90^\circ, 0^\circ, 0^\circ) \\
q_{\text{pitch}} &= \text{getQuaternionFromEulers}(0^\circ, 0^\circ, 0^\circ) \\
q_{\text{roll}} &= \text{getQuaternionFromEulers}(0^\circ, 0^\circ, 90^\circ)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
q_{\text{compensation}} &= \left(q_{\text{roll}} \times q_{\text{pitch}} \times q_{\text{yaw}}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}
Here is what my $getQuaternionFromEulers$ function computes :
\begin{align*}
  \text{cy} &= \cos\left(\frac{\text{yaw}}{2}\right) \\
  \text{sy} &= \sin\left(\frac{\text{yaw}}{2}\right) \\
  \text{cp} &= \cos\left(\frac{\text{pitch}}{2}\right) \\
  \text{sp} &= \sin\left(\frac{\text{pitch}}{2}\right) \\
  \text{cr} &= \cos\left(\frac{\text{roll}}{2}\right) \\
  \text{sr} &= \sin\left(\frac{\text{roll}}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  q_w &= \text{cr} \cdot \text{cp} \cdot \text{cy} + \text{sr} \cdot \text{sp} \cdot \text{sy} \\
  q_x &= \text{sr} \cdot \text{cp} \cdot \text{cy} - \text{cr} \cdot \text{sp} \cdot \text{sy} \\
  q_y &= \text{cr} \cdot \text{sp} \cdot \text{cy} + \text{sr} \cdot \text{cp} \cdot \text{sy} \\
  q_z &= \text{cr} \cdot \text{cp} \cdot \text{sy} - \text{sr} \cdot \text{sp} \cdot \text{cy}
\end{align*}
2. Compensating the IMU quaternion with $q_{compensation}$
$q_{imuCompensated} = q_{imu} * q_{compensation}$
3. Rotating my acceleration, gyro and magnetometer vectors using $q_{compensation}$
Here is how I try to rotate $v_{acceleration}$ to go back to body frame reference :
$v_{\text{accelerationCompensated}} = q_{\text{compensation}} \cdot q_{\text{acceleration}} \cdot q_{\text{compensation}}^{-1}$
$q_{acceleration}$ is a quaternion with x, y and z being my vector components and with a 0 scalar component.
4. Strange results
When I test this code with 90° YAW and 90° ROLL, the signs of the X and Y values of $v_{accelerationCompensated}$ are wrong. So I'm not even sure my calculus is correct.
When applying 90° yaw :

x becomes y
y becomes -x
z remains unchanged

When applying 90° roll :

x remains unchanged
y becomes z
z becomes -y

Which means that finally :

The new X is the old Z
The new Y is the old X
The new Z is the old -Y

But on this exact same position, my code is giving me "-1" of acceleration on my bodyframe Z component instead of "1" (as the Z axis is pointing down). Same goes when I point the bodyframe Y component down, it shows me "-1" instead of "1".
It's really hard for me to understand what is going on. If my logic above is correct then I guess it has something to do with my axis being inverted.
Thank you very much for anyone that can explain what could go wrong or if I made mistakes.

could this be just a gimbal lock artifact?

I don't think so, I think a gimbal lock problem would manifest itself by the loss of 1 axis of freedom.
